# Does application scoped beans run on seperate thread in JSF?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I am using JSF to create a web app.

I have an application scoped bean  that has a infinite loop so that it periodically performs an action.

My problem is that this bean (due to the infinite loop) is blocking the whole application. I thought that the bean would run on its own thread. Isnt that the case with JSF, that each managed bean is running on own thread by default?

Should I create a thread and let the infinite loop run in that thread instead?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Does application scoped beans run on seperate thread in JSF?*

No, it definitely doesn't.

> *Should I create a thread and let the infinite loop run in that thread instead?*

No, you shouldn't. You should just create a scheduled task. Best way to that is to use a `@Singleton @Schedule` EJB.

```
@Singleton
public class SomeDailyJob {

    @Schedule(hour="0", minute="0", second="0", persistent=false)
    public void run() {
        // Do your job here which should run daily at midnight.
    }

}
```

That's all. No additional configuration of manually messing with threads necessary. If you want to access its state -if any- from in a JSF managed bean, just inject with `@EJB` the usual way.

#### See also:

- [Spawning threads in a JSF managed bean for scheduled tasks using a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499534/applicationscope-bean-that-uses-a-timertask-sheduler-good-or-bad/)
- [Java mail how to send automatically an email on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493959/java-mail-how-to-send-automatically-an-email-on-condition/)

Comment: thnx a lot. I m gonna try this :)